# VS Code - Window API Dependencies

Tags: c++, windows, dependencies, winsock2

New to C++ so be kind! I have researched a fair amount before asking this. Currently I have a VS Code project being developed on an Apple laptop for Windows environment. From my understanding these files are part of the Windows API and are not something that an Apple product will contain natively. Where can I get such files or is there an SDK I can download to support this project? In Java and Python, there are dependencies managers such as PIP and Maven which usually solve such problems.

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
```

While this may not be extremely important, [here](http://niiconsulting.com/checkmate/2018/02/malware-development-welcome-dark-side-part-2-1/) is the link to the project I am trying to make.

Comment: I believe mingw provides compatible headers.

Comment: @drescherjm no, mingw provides posix headers on windows

Comment: As you have noted these are headers for the windows API and are not available on other platforms, you might be able to get something to work with [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) but you'd be better off using a cross platform libraries like Qt or Boost

Comment: So if I understand correctly, some compilers may have these files which are used at compile time? Wine looks promising and will check it out!

Comment: There is supposed to be a `w32api` package from mingw with the headers. http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MinGW it is listed in the packages included with MinGW section.

Comment: The reason I mentioned that is I have long ago built windows executables under linux using mingw. You can't run these native on linux but you can use wine or run them on a windows box.

Comment: @drescherjm yep, mingw will allow you to build windows software on another platform, you won't be able to run it though. The headers just provide access to the Windows API but don't provide the implementation

Comment: The linked article in the question is about creating malware for windows. I would expect a windows machine may be necessary to test the technique anyways.